# How do i turn the camera left right up and down using the keys W S A D?

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

At the top of my code i added:

```
Matrix rotation;
private float angleRightLeft = 0f;
private float angleUpDown = 0f;
```

In the constructor i did:

```
rotation = Matrix.Identity;
```

In the Update method i call the keyes:

```
float timeDifference = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds / 1000.0f;
ProcessInput(timeDifference);
```

In the draw method im using the variable angleRightLeft to rotate the world(terrain):

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            graphics.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
            device.Clear(Color.Black);
            RasterizerState rs = new RasterizerState();
            rs.CullMode = CullMode.None;
            rs.FillMode = FillMode.WireFrame;
            device.RasterizerState = rs;
            //Matrix worldMatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(-terrainWidth / 2.0f, 0, terrainHeight / 2.0f);
            //worldMatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(-terrainWidth / 2.0f, 0, terrainHeight / 2.0f) * Matrix.CreateRotationY(angle);
            worldMatrix = Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(this.rotation.Left,angleRightLeft);
            worldMatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(-terrainWidth / 2.0f, 0, terrainHeight / 2.0f) * Matrix.CreateRotationY(angleRightLeft);
            effect.CurrentTechnique = effect.Techniques["ColoredNoShading"];
            effect.Parameters["xView"].SetValue(viewMatrix);
            effect.Parameters["xProjection"].SetValue(projectionMatrix);
            effect.Parameters["xWorld"].SetValue(worldMatrix);

            foreach (EffectPass pass in effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
            {
                pass.Apply();

                device.DrawUserIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, vertices, 0, vertices.Length, indices, 0, indices.Length / 3, VertexPositionColor.VertexDeclaration);
            }
```

In the draw method i did:

```
worldMatrix = Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(this.rotation.Left,angleRightLeft);
worldMatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(-terrainWidth / 2.0f, 0, terrainHeight / 2.0f) * Matrix.CreateRotationY(angleRightLeft);
```

So if i press the A(Left) key its moving left but clicking on D dosent turn it right.
This is the keys process method:

```
private void ProcessInput(float amount)
        {
            previousState = currentState;
            currentState = Mouse.GetState();
            Vector3 moveVector = new Vector3(0 , 0 , 0);
            KeyboardState keyState = Keyboard.GetState();
            if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up) || keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
                //cameraPosition += new Vector3(0.0f, 50.0f, +100);


            if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down) || keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
                //cameraPosition -= new Vector3(0.0f, 50.0f, +100);


            if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right) || keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
                //cameraPosition += new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
                angleRightLeft += 0.05f;

            if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left) || keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
                //cameraPosition += new Vector3(-1, 0, 0);
                angleRightLeft -= 0.05f;

            if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Q))
                cameraPosition += new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
            if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Z))
                cameraPosition += new Vector3(0, -1, 0);
            if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
            {
                this.graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 800;
                this.graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 600;
                this.graphics.IsFullScreen = false;
                this.graphics.ApplyChanges();
            }
            if (this.graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth < 1920)
            {

                if (WasDoubleClick())
                {
                    changeScreenNode(this.graphics, 1920, 1080, true);
                }
            }

            if (WasMouseLeftClick())
            {
                previousClick = DateTime.Now;
            }
        }
```

If i move this line: angleRightLeft += 0.05f;
From the D key and put it under the W key then when i press A its moving left and W move it right.

But i want to do that when i click W and S it will move the world up and down and if i click A and D it will move the world left and right.
So i created the variable angleUpDown but something is wrong with the Draw method rotating the world.

How can i do it to work according to keys pressed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So from what I gather from your question is that pressing `W` with `angleRightLeft += 0.05f;` placed under that key press works for moving right, but pressing `D` does not.

One thing which I would guess is causing this is the way you have the following code:

```
if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up) || keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
    //cameraPosition += new Vector3(0.0f, 50.0f, +100);

if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down) || keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
    //cameraPosition -= new Vector3(0.0f, 50.0f, +100);

if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right) || keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
    //cameraPosition += new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
    angleRightLeft += 0.05f;
```

If you do not enclose your `if-statement` with brackets `{}`, then the line following the statement is seen as the the line to execute once the `if-statement` equates to **true**.

Because you have these lines commented out, I am presuming that your compiler is seeing the next `if-statement` as the one to execute, and then the same again for the following if-statement.

If you debugged and stepped down through the code you would most likely see this happening.

So I suggest you either enclose your statements in brackets, or else comment out the whole if statement rather than just the code inside it:

```
if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up) || keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.W)){
    //cameraPosition += new Vector3(0.0f, 50.0f, +100);
}


if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down) || keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.S)){
    //cameraPosition -= new Vector3(0.0f, 50.0f, +100);
}

if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right) || keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D)){
    //cameraPosition += new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
    angleRightLeft += 0.05f;
}

if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left) || keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A)){
    //cameraPosition += new Vector3(-1, 0, 0);
    angleRightLeft -= 0.05f;
}
```

Comment: But you said it works ok when you put the line `angleRightLeft += 0.05f` under the check for `W`, which would suggest the problem is in your key press logic.